# What's the difference in meaning between the verbs schnauben, schnaufen, and schniefen?

Tags: meaning

Can someone please explain the differences in meaning between **schnauben, schnaufen**, and **schniefen**?
The dictionaries suggest some translations but to a degree they overlap and I feel like it might be helpful (and more effective) to have the meanings described in a few sentences.

Comment: They are quite dissimilar in meaning, so looking up them in a dictionary should answer your question. Voting to close.

Comment: Rossi, you should really show your own research - as it stands, this question risks being closed due to lack if own research.

Comment: Warum wollt ihr jede zweite Frage schließen? Ich finde das eine gute Frage, die gar nicht so einfach zu beantworten ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich könnte diese Frage sogar auf Englisch beantworten, aber wir erwarten *ein Minimum an Eigeninitiative* der Fragesteller in Form von z.B. "in meinem Lexikon steht für...". Und jede Frage wird zuerst auf "hold" gesetzt. Wenn OP sie ergänzt, bin ich gern die Erste, die sie wieder zum Öffnen nominiert...

Comment: Rossi, please see the second bullet point on the help page about [on-topic questions](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and @HubertSchölnast might choose to refresh his memory, too. Should you not have a dictionary at hand, perhaps you would like to try [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc).

Comment: Stephie & chirlu, I belong to several language-learning websites and even native german speakers have asked the exact same question as the one I've posted here. If you should take the time to look them up on the dictionary links you've provided, you will see that they all share a similar definition.  Instead of hampering and hindering (yes, same meaning here, too, right?) my learning experience as well as others, I suggest you leave those of us trying to learn other languages and their nuances be......... As such, I thank Hubert Schoelnast for the clarification.

Comment: @chirlu: Note that as by [this Meta voting](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/848/2594) and as of now, questions asking for differences do not have to indicate prior research.

Comment: @Rossi I *did* check dict.cc, in fact I did so *before* posting my comment. There is *one* translation overlapping between "schniefen" and "schnauben" and between "schnaufen" and "schnauben", none between "schniefen" and "schnaufen". Besides, no one is trying to hamper, let alone hinder you in any way. I simply asked you (nicely, I hope) to put a tiny bit more effort into your question - making an interesting question into an interesting *and* well-researched one is not hampering IMHO.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: So any off-topic question asking for the meaning of _laufen_ could be repaired simply by turning it into a question asking for the difference between _laufen_ and _Wasser_?

Comment: @chirlu: Don’t tell me; I did not vote on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es wäre sehr schwer für mich, das auf Englisch zu erklären, dazu reicht mein Englisch leider nicht aus. Daher antworte ich in meiner Muttersprache.

### schnauben

Luft durch die Nase ausblasen. Beim Schnauben entsteht ist ein starker Luftstrom, der durch die Nase austritt. Er ist so stark, dass er deutlich hörbar ist. Das Schnauben ist ein einmaliger Vorgang, der normalerweise nicht automatisch bei jedem Atemzug wiederholt wird. Er kann aber natürlich beliebig oft wiederholt werden.

### schnaufen

Heftig atmen. Entweder weil man gerade etwas anstrengendes tut oder getan hat (z.B. Sport oder körperliche Arbeit) oder weil man Probleme mit der Atmung hat (eine Erkrankung, z.B. Asthma). Jemand der schnauft ist »außer Atem«. Bei Schnaufen atmet man fast immer durch den Mund, weil die Luftmenge, die man ein- und ausatmen will, zu groß ist um durch die Nase geleitet zu werden. Dieses Kriterium ist aber nicht zwingend. Man kann auch durch die Nase schnaufen. Im Gegensatz zum einmaligen Schnauben ist das Schnaufen etwas, was man über eine längere Zeit bei jedem Atemzug macht.

### schniefen

Etwas durch die Nase einsaugen. Wenn man Schnupfen hat, fließt ein Sekret aus der Nase, und dieses Sekret kann man durch ein starkes Einatmen durch die Nase wieder in die Nase saugen. Diesen Vorgang nennt man schniefen. Man kann aber auch z.B. Kokain schniefen. Auch wenn man weint muss man schniefen, weil dann die Tränenflüssigkeit durch den Tränenkanal vom Auge in die Nase fließt, und dann natürlich vorne aus der Nase heraus laufen würde wenn man sie durch Schniefen nicht wieder in die Nase zurück saugen würde. Alternativ kann man sich in diesem Fall auch schnäuzen, dabei wird das Nasensekret aus der Nase heraus geblasen (üblicherweise in ein Taschentuch).

Comment: Umgangssprachlich kann "schnaufen" auch einfach nur "atmen" bedeuten. Hier ist z. B. folgender Dialog möglich: "Was machst du gerade?" - "Schnaufen." Das heißt dann so viel wie "ich mache gerade nichts."

Comment: Ich bin richtig überrascht, dass in Österreich *schnaufen* anscheinend nicht anstelle von *atmen* verwendet wird, wie es in Oberbayern der Fall ist. In unseren Erste-Hilfe- und San-Kursen hat es immer geheißen »Ansprechen, wackeln, Mundraumkontrolle, Kopf überstrecken, schnauft er?« ;)

Comment: @Chris: Nein, gewöhnliches Atmen heißt - zumindest in Österreich - »atmen«. Das Wort »schnaufen« verwenden wir so, wie in meiner Antwort beschrieben.

Comment: Für alle drei gilt: es handelt sich (vielleicht mit Ausnahme desjenigen Schnaufens, das Jan meint und das ich so auch kenne) um geräuschvolle Tätigkeiten im Unterschied zum praktisch geräuschlosen Atmen.